# This problem of probabilities can be solved?

Tags: probability

> "John and Peter are solving a math problem. Probability that John will get a correct solution is 1/8. Probability that Peter will get a correct solution is 1/12. Both solving independently. If both compute incorrectly, they receive same result with probability 1/1001. Both have received same result. What is probability that result is correct?"

If $A,B$ are independents events and $M$ any event such that:
$$P(A)=1/8,P(B)=1/12 \text{ and } P(M | A^{c} \cap B^{c}) = 1/1001$$

Can we find the value of $P(A \cap B | M)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're not saying that $A, B, M$ are independent.  You can find $P(M \cap A^c \cap B^c)$, but what you need is $P(M \cap A \cap B/P(M))$, and have hardly any information about 
that: it could be anywhere from $0$ to $1000/1001$.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the problem, because this says:
"John and Peter are solving a math problem. Probability that John will
get a correct solution is 1/8. Probability that Peter will get a correct solution is 1/12. Both solving independently. If both compute incorrectly, they receive same result with probability 1/1001. Both have received same result. What is probability that result is correct?"

Comment: @Inzit, you missed some information from that text.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe I misunderstood the problem, because this says: "John and Peter are solving a math problem. Probability that John will get a correct solution is 1/8. Probability that Peter will get a correct solution is 1/12. Both solving independently. If both compute incorrectly, they receive same result with probability 1/1001. Both have received same result. What is probability that result is correct?"

There are *many* incorrect answers.  There is *only* one correct answer (call it $c$).  So if they compute correctly they receive the same result with probability $1$.

Also if one computes correctly and the other does not, then they will certainly not have the same answer.

So, we have $\mathsf P(J=c\cap P=c) = \frac 1 8 \times \frac 1 {12}
\\ \mathsf P(J\neq c\cap P\neq c) = \frac 7 8 \times \frac {11}{12}
\\ \mathsf P(J=P \mid J=c \oplus P=c) = 0 
\\ \mathsf P(J=P\mid J=c\cap P=c) = 1
\\ \mathsf P(J=P\mid J\neq c\cap P\neq c) = \frac 1 {1001}$

Now can you find: $\mathsf P(J=c\cap P=c\mid J=P) = \frac{P(J=P\mid J=c\cap P=c)P(J=c\cap P=c)}{P(J=P\mid J=c\cap P=c)P(J=c\cap P=c)+P(J=P\mid J\neq c\cap P\neq c)P(J\neq c\cap P\neq c)}$

---

Or using your symbols:

$\mathsf P(A\cap B) = \frac 1 8 \times \frac 1 {12}
\\ \mathsf P(A^\complement \cap B^\complement) = \frac 7 8 \times \frac {11}{12}
\\ \mathsf P(M \mid (A\cap B^\complement )\cup(A^\complement \cap B)) = 0 
\\ \mathsf P(M \mid A\cap B) = 1
\\ \mathsf P(M\mid A^\complement \cap B^\complement ) = \frac 1 {1001}$

Now can you find: $\mathsf P(A\cap B\mid M) = \frac{\mathsf P(M\mid A\cap B)\mathsf P(A\cap B)}{\mathsf P(M\mid A\cap B)\mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(M\mid A^\complement\cap B^\complement)\mathsf P(A^\complement\cap B^\complement)}$